# wordpress bitnami my page colapse database

Tags: database, wordpress, bitnami

I am not a programer neither work full time in this i make a page for a client and try to change the email from user@example.com to a personal trying different methods the last one i sue was trying to use the wp_mail_smtp  plugin and then the page says database error and i have 1222 lines of error and in the front page with te same problem of table don't appear, the page is mangooglamping.com and in there shows some problems too, i do not know how to restart the database and i am using the ssh of google cloud because i have everything online and in the tutorials i follow they put all in the web and do not explain how to download the page to local mac

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami engineer here, you can easily modify the email address of the user by running these commands in the database

- Obtain the id of the user

```
mysql -u root -p bitnami_wordpress -e "SELECT * FROM wp_users;"
```

- Update the email address

```
mysql -u root -h DATABASEHOST -p bitnami_wordpress -e "UPDATE wp_users SET user_email='NEW-EMAIL' WHERE ID='ADMIN-ID';"
```

You can learn more about how to do this in our documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/reset-wp-admin-email-address/

> i do not know how to restart the database

Simply run

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart mysql
```